# Are processes bound to cores?

Tags: linux, process

Let's say I have a CPU with lots of cores. Is a given process, once started, bound to one of the cores?

Does that mean that a process can become sluggish even if there are several unused cores? For example, core0 is being used by process A and B, process A is using 100% of the core, and process B can not run, even though core1 is completely free.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processes are not intrinsically bound to cores. Each time a process is scheduled for execution it may be executed by any core in its affinity list. If the affinity list has not been set explicitly, a process can be run on any core.

You can check or set the affinity set for a process with the `taskset` command (see `man taskset` for its documentation). In particular, it writes that,

> The Linux scheduler will honour the given CPU affinity and the process will not run on any other CPUs. Note that the  Linux  scheduler  also  supports  natural  CPU affinity: the scheduler attempts to keep processes on the same CPU as long as practical for performance reasons. Therefore, forcing a specific CPU affinity is useful only in certain applications.

Example

```
sleep 1000 & slpid=$!
echo "PID of sleep is $slpid"            # 5221

taskset --pid $slpid
pid 5221's current affinity mask: 3      # bitmask

taskset --cpu-list --pid $slpid
pid 5221's current affinity list: 0,1    # list of potential cores

taskset --cpu-list --pid 0 $slpid
pid 5221's current affinity list: 0,1
pid 5221's new affinity list: 0          # bound now only to core 0

kill $slpid                              # all done, tidy up
```

Comment: Does it mean that processes can start in any core, or that they can run in any core? Said otherwise: can a process start in core0, run for a while there, and continue running in core1?

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now. So normally I would see a process jumping around cores, according to core availability, specially in a system when one or several cores are experiencing high load, right? Is the default policy to allow a process to run in any core, if `taskset`is not used?

Comment: The default policy is any core, yes. (I can't quickly find documentation to that effect but it's implied in the man page.)